# How to use com.android.internal.telephony.Phone (Internal API)

Tags: android, api, internal

I'm trying to use internal APIs to obtain some low level network informations (Ec/Io, RSSI and RSCP for GSM phone), I was able to import these APIs and, in particular, I would like to use com.android.internal.telephony.Phone and com.android.internal.telephony.PhoneFactory.
But when I try to use PhoneFactory like this:

> Phone mPhone;
>   Phone localPhone = PhoneFactory.getDefaultPhone();
>   this.mPhone = localPhone;

I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: PhoneFactory.getDefaultPhone Must Be Called from Looper thread
```

as described in the [source code](http://hi-android.info/src/com/android/internal/telephony/PhoneFactory.java.html#155) of Android PhoneFactory.java:

```
public static getDefaultPhone Phone () {
     if (sLooper! Looper.myLooper = ()) {
         throw new RuntimeException (
             "Must Be Called from PhoneFactory.getDefaultPhone Looper thread");
     }

     if (! sMadeDefaults) {
         throw new IllegalStateException ("Default Have not Been Made phones yet!");
     }
     sProxyPhone return;
}
```

Someone has already tried to use the class Phone with success?

Answer (score 2):

The sdk does not support this or even recommends this officially, however, [you can do this by reflection](http://mylockforandroid.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/phone/src/i4nc4mp/myLock/phone/CallPrompt.java).

The risk is that any change in the framework will break your code.

Comment: Hi the reflection method is very interesting to me, what do you think, can this be detected by google and prevent your app to get featured or worse banned?

Comment: did you get any further with this? I'd really love to use this class to change my phone number (the network didn't update the SIM when I brought my phone over from another provider). I'm on KitKat and the SDK doesn't show these classes as existing.

Comment: @Erden nope, I put the SIM in an iPhone and did it.